# C# Receive transaction detail from Paypal

Tags: c#, paypal, transactions

I'm using c# and attempting to intergrate my site with Paypal.  I have have been able to send date to the paypal and get paypal to return to my site, but there is not transaction details.

The method below should get the Transaction Id, Payment status, amount and currancy.  But sadly it gets none of the data.  Could some please help?

```
public ActionResult paypalreturn(string tx, string st, string amt, string cc)
    {

        string subject = "Audit -  Paypal return";
        string buildemail = "tx: " + tx;
        buildemail += "st: " + st;
        buildemail += "<br>amt: " + amt;
        buildemail += "<br>cc: " + cc;

        Libraries.Email.Product.SendAudit(subject, buildemail);
        return RedirectToAction("Basket", "Product");

    }//END METHOD Payment
```

Comment: How are you trying to get the data returned from you?  Are you trying to read the API response from your API call to process the payment, are you trying to use PDT or IPN?

Comment: Thanks.  To my understanding on the return url I pass to Paypal it Post a reply with the parameters.  It calls this method on the return, but the Parameters do not get populated.  I've enabled the IPN, but the IPN does not seem to work.

Comment: The POST that sends information back to the return URL and the IPN are 2 different things.  If you are wanting to have data returned to your return URL you would either need to set up PDT or use the variable "rm".  PDT will allow you to validate the data, using the rm variable will just post the data to your return URL.  IPN is a separate feature where PayPal sends a POST to your server that you validate.  It is behind the scenes and the buyer does not see this on the return URL.  Which method are you trying to use with your return page, PDT or using the rm variable?

Comment: i think you have solution
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538334/get-paypapl-donation-transaction-detail-in-html-with-donation-button-implemented)